# How to resolve Vitesse formatting issue?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, formatting, vite

I just created a project based on the https://github.com/antfu/vitesse template. But I've some formatting issue.

If I ask for formating in VS Code, each "first" attribute of an html element is on the same line as the start of element, which is something I would have expected, but it raises warning:

```
Expected a linebreak before this attribute.eslintvue/first-attribute-linebreak
```

or sometimes:

```
Expected indentation of 2 spaces but found 4 spaces.eslintvue/html-indent
```

If I hit Ctrl+S, then I get no errors anymore, all the attributes(including first one) are on a new line.

Honestly, I don't really care which is kept, but how to synchronize the two of them? It jumps a lot every time I format and it's disturbing.

Thank you very much

**EDIT**

After @tony19's comment, I tried to set volar as default formatter. So my `.vscode/settings.json` looks like:

```
{
  "cSpell.words": [
    "Vitesse",
    "Vite",
    "unocss",
    "vitest",
    "vueuse",
    "pinia",
    "demi",
    "antfu",
    "iconify",
    "intlify",
    "vitejs",
    "unplugin",
    "pnpm"
  ],
  "i18n-ally.sourceLanguage": "en",
  "i18n-ally.keystyle": "nested",
  "i18n-ally.localesPaths": [
    "locales"
  ],
  "i18n-ally.sortKeys": true,
  "prettier.enable": false,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "files.associations": {
    "*.css": "postcss"
  },
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar"
}
```

But I've still the same behavior. `shift+alt+F` format like this:

```
  <div id="simple"
       class="toto">
    index
  </div>
```

and when I save, it formats like this:

```
  <div
    id="simple"
    class="toto"
  >
    index
  </div>
```

I must admit that I'm not a big fan of having the end `>` on a single line but as far as the comportment is coherent I'm happy
(I also tried `"editor.defaultFormatter": "dbaeumer.vscode-eslint"` and  `"editor.defaultFormatter": "antfu.vite"` without any luck.

Comment: VS Code is probably configured to use a formatter that differs from Volar. What is it set to? Check your user `settings.json` for `editor.defaultFormatter` (on macOS: `~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/settings.json`). For `.vue` files, make sure `[vue].editor.defaultFormatter` is set to `Vue.volar`.

Comment: @tony19 I don't want to modify my global installation, since I'm mostly doing angular app and have side projects. I've tried to modify my `.vscode/settings.json`(check my updated question) to force volar as default formatter, without any luck.

Comment: It should be `"[vue]": { "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar" }` (i.e., the `[vue]` key is missing from your `settings.json`).

Comment: I also added the `[vue]` section(I taught that if it was the default, it should override it anyway. But I still have the issue. Also, apparently, in my `%APPDATA%\Code\User\settings.json`, I already have a vue section with Volar as defaultFormatter :( It feels like that vitesse uses ESLINT to format, not volar. But I'm not sure how to make sure it's in adequations between the editor and when it saves.